# How to get similar properties using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file like

```
<node>
  <properties>
    <property name="titleENG">English title</property>
    <property name="titleFRE">French title</property>
    <property name="descENG">English description</property>
    <property name="descFRE">French description</property>
    ...
  </properties>
</node>
```

and as output, I want a CSV file like

```
title, English title, French title
desc, English description, French description
...
```

Let's assume that I know the available languages, but I don't know the available properties (title, desc, ...)

I can get the English strings with the following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="property">
    <xsl:if test="@name[ends-with(.,'ENG')]">
      <xsl:variable name="key" select="substring(@name,1,string-length(@name)-3)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>, <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/><xsl:text>&#10;     </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But inside the 'if', I also need the value of the property with `name=concat($key,'FRE')` How can I do this?
Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**
I guess I can rephrase my question to (since I can easily transform my current set into this one): suppose I have an XML like

```
<node>
 <properties>
  <property name="dummy"></property>
  <property name="title" lang="ENG">English title</property>
  <property name="title" lang="FRE">French title</property>
  <property name="desc" lang="ENG">English description</property>
  <property name="desc" lang="FRE">French description</property>
  ...
 </properties>
</node>
```

How can I create a (CSV) output with in this case two rows, the name in the first column and the English, French translations in the next columns?

Comment: **1.** "*Let's assume that I know the available languages*" Where would this knowledge reside? **2.** Your stylesheet says version 1.0, but you are using version 2.0 function ends-with(). **3.** If your output is CSV, why are you copying nodes?

Comment: **1.** I see that as a separate problem; worst-case I hardcode them, best-case I try to use some kind of array-variables but I haven't looked at it yet. **2.** My online xslt test tool didn't complain; thanks for pointing this out. **3.** I guess you mean that I can omit the first template? At one point I seemed to need it to recurse through the xml but apparently that's indeed not needed anymore.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: **1.** It's not a separate problem, because we need to know where to take them from in order to think up a working solution; if you say they can be hard-coded into the stylesheet, then we know. We still don't know **2.** if you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. I mean in production, not for on-line testing.

Comment: XSLT 2.0 is OK (sorry to be not more explicit)

Comment: If you can change your source XML, you might also consider using standard language codes (ISO 639-1) and the `xml:lang` attribute to designate your language. With that, you can also use the `lang()` function to select nodes. And you can import a language code table (I believe that in IANA.org you might find them in XML, CSV, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> XSLT 2.0 is OK

Actually, I didn't have time to switch to XSLT 2.0 mode and this will work in both:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />

<xsl:key name="prop-by-prefix" match="property" use="substring(@name, 1, string-length(@name)-3)" />
<xsl:key name="prop-by-name" match="property" use="@name" />

<my:languages>
    <lang>ENG</lang>
    <lang>FRE</lang>
</my:languages>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="node/properties/property[count(. | key('prop-by-prefix', substring(@name, 1, string-length(@name)-3))[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="substring(@name, 1, string-length(@name)-3)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$prefix"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/my:languages/lang">
            <xsl:variable name="name" select="concat($prefix, .)"/>
            <!-- switch context back to source document in order to use key -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$root">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('prop-by-name', $name)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input of:

```
<node>
  <properties>
    <property name="titleENG">English title</property>
    <property name="titleFRE">French title</property>
    <property name="descENG">English description</property>
    <property name="descFRE">French description</property>
  </properties>
</node>
```

the following result is obtained:

```
title,English title,French title
desc,English description,French description
```

---

### Added:

I have just now noticed you have changed your input. This makes it much simpler:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="prop-by-name" match="property" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="node/properties/property[count(. | key('prop-by-name', @name)[1]) = 1][@lang]">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('prop-by-name', @name)">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you are using XSLT 2.0 (or an XSLT 1.0 processor that supports the EXSLT set:distinct) function), you can use that instead of the Muenchian grouping.

Comment: This works indeed, thanks! Can you explain one more thing though: why do we need the `<xsl:for-each select="$root">`? Why can't we just write `<xsl:value-of select="//property[@name=$name]"/>`

Comment: @MarcVanDaele I prefer using key to retrieve "related" data. However, you cannot use key across documents, so I use `<xsl:for-each select="$root">` to switch the context temporarily back to the source XML document in order to use the key.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your `$key` variable outside the if:

```
<xsl:variable name="key" select="substring(@name,1,string-length(@name)-3)" />
```

And get the suffix using `substring-after` the `$key` in the `@name` attribute:

```
<xsl:variable name="suffix" select="substring-after(@name, $key)"/>
```

You can then test independently of knowing the suffix:

```
<xsl:if test="@name[ends-with(.,$suffix)]">
```

Comment: I guess the if-test becomes a no-op in this case since it will always be true. Note that there are also language-independent properties <property name="dummy">dummy</property> (which was important info missing, sorry for that). I'm still struggling to get a single line containing the key and all it's translations on one line (like "title, English title, French title")

Comment: Yes. You're right. It would be necessary to extract the suffix and compare it with the avaliable languages. The `dummy` properties could be filtered out as well. I'll edit the answer when I get back to my computer. But I think Michael's answer up there solves your problem.